# Questions about stuff learned in school

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Is, "I learned [x] in school, is it really true" on topic or does there have to be a notable claim.  Sometimes the things we learn are based on just A.) The half-informed understanding of our teachers of B.) the half-comprehending ability of ourselves.

So I'd like to know if just challenging the things I assume to be true because I learned them in school is good fodder for this site.  [I asked one question before](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4777/was-the-new-deal-of-the-1930s-a-spontaneous-invention-or-a-natural-progression) and it was closed - but I wrote 'I was just wondering' which apparently is a keyword for destruction (which I heartily respect).

Would saying, I learned this in such and such a school and I'd like to know if it's BS be OK?  Does it matter whether it was learned at a university or elementary school?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter where the claim comes from, however:

- it should be a notable claim. My high school teacher insisted that we could call the square root of two, "radical-2". Asking whether this is correct on this site does certainly not reach notability. In other words: nobody cares if it's too specific.
- it should be a claim with substance, either with a lot of people believing in it (e.g. [Has man walked on the Moon?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/has-man-walked-on-the-moon)) or with some remote chance of being correct (e.g. [Is it better to sleep before midnight?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/is-it-better-to-sleep-before-midnight))
- it should not be confrontational or speculative in nature (e.g. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/what-can-explain-the-phenomenon-of-street-light-interference-syndrome-closed)

Comment: +1, although notability is hard to demonstrate for some specific claims made by teachers unless the OP does a lot of research upfront.

Comment: @kon: not really. "My teacher says that homeopathy is real medicine, is it true?" :-)

Comment: Counter-example: my (otherwise great!) biology teacher said (on the topic of evolution, which he otherwise avidly defended) “there are still some developments which cannot be explained via evolution alone and which require new theories.” He was *not* intending this as a sneaking attempt to introduce creationism into the classroom. He just sucked at evolutionary biology. Now, this isn’t a notable claim that I know of, but I still think that it’s a common misconception among lay people and would be suitable on this site.

Comment: @Konrad: On the other hand, the current evolution theory does not explain "everything", therefore there IS still a need for new theories (just like Newtonian or even relativistic physics do not explain everything and there is need for new theories), therefore I would call such claim not false, but rather tautological.

Comment: @Suma His example was the transition from water dwellers to land dweller and the development of lungs. This is completely explained by evolution. In fact, I don’t know of *anything* in evolution that cannot be explained by it (*this* may sound tautological). Either way, I think your claim that “the current evolution theory does not explain ‘everything’” is a bit misinformed as well – while there are certainly gaps in understanding (e.g. the role of epigenetics), nothing suggests that fundamental new theories not compatible with currently known evolutionary mechanisms is required.

Comment: This looks like a small misunderstanding between us around the word theory. I am not claiming what is needed are "fundamental new theories not compatible with currently known evolutionary mechanisms", just that there are still some unexplained areas ("gaps"), which need "new theories". I expect those new theories will be most likely be well compatible with current theories.

Comment: @Suma My explanation was crap. => [please read my explanation in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/868/evilution).